# Is it possible to implement a std::list using unique pointers?

Tags: c++, list, unique-ptr

List.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <initializer_list>


class List{
    public:
        List();
        List(const std::initializer_list<int> &list);
        ~List();
        int size() const;

        void push_back(int val);
        void pop_back();
        void pop_front();
        friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, const List &l);

    private:
        void printNodes() const;
        struct Node {
            Node(int data) : data(data) {}
            std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
            Node *previous;
            int data;
        };
        int len;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
        Node *tail;
};
```

List.cpp

```
#include "List.h"

List::List() : len(0), head(nullptr), tail(nullptr){
}

List::List(const std::initializer_list<int> &list) : len(0), head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {
    for (auto &elem : list)
        push_back(elem);
}

List::~List() {
}

void List::push_back(int val){
    if (tail == nullptr) {
        head = std::make_unique<Node>(val);
        tail = head.get();
        head->next = nullptr;
        head->previous = nullptr;
        len++;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = std::make_unique<Node>(val);
        (tail->next)->previous = tail;
        tail = tail->next.get();
        tail->next = nullptr;
        len++;
    }
}

void List::pop_back(){
    if(len == 1){
        auto node = head.release();
        delete node;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }else{
        // tail->previous;

    }
}

void List::pop_front(){
    if(len == 1){
        auto node = head.release();
        delete node;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }else{


    }
}

void List::printNodes() const{
    Node *temp = head.get();

    while (temp != nullptr) {
        std::cout << temp->data << "\n";
        temp = (temp->next).get();
    }
}

int List::size() const{
    return len;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream & os, const List & l){
    l.printNodes();

    return os;
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    List l{3, 5, 1, 6, 7};

    cout << l << endl;
}
```

Hello Stack Overflow, I'm a Data structures student, and as practice, I'm trying to recreate `std::list` using smart pointers. Based on what I have read, it appears that `unique_ptr` should be the default one to use, with `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` only being used where `unique_ptr` cannot due to speed differences. Unfortunately, I have hit a wall when trying to implement `pop_back()` and `pop_front()`. Do I have to adopt shared pointers to complete the entire std::list reimplementation, or is there a way these functions can be done using unique pointers?

Comment: Since apparently you have a doubly-linked list, `unique_ptr` doesn't make sense, as each node would have at least two pointers pointing to it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ⏬

Comment: `auto node = head.release(); delete node;`? Why use smart pointers at all if you `delete` manually?

Comment: On the surface, I think `head = std::move(head->next);` should work for `pop_front`; you don't need a special case for one-element list.

Comment: @UnholySheep For pop_back() I couldn't think of any other way to remove the last node other than releasing the ownership to a raw pointer, and getting rid of the node manually. Is there a more effective way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly possible. Let's start with `pop_back`:

You have a pointer to the node already with `tail`, but that's not the interesting one, since it's just a raw pointer. The pointer that you need is the `unique_ptr` to that same node. Where is that pointer stored? Is there an easy way to get to it starting from `tail`?

Once you have the `unique_ptr`, unchaining the node from the list is as easy as [resetting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) that pointer. Note that there is no need to call `release` and `delete` the node manually.

Now for `pop_front`: Here you already have the `unique_ptr` in hand, it's `head`. But you have to be careful as the whole list rests on this one. Resetting the `head` will make the entire list disappear. So be sure to detach the rest of the list from the `head` and reattach it with the `list` first. If you do this properly, deleting the original `head` will not even be a worry for you. Try it out!

Be sure to draw a picture of the list to visualize which node points where. It's rather difficult to keep all of this information in your head at once.

Comment: Ah, ok. So reset() calls the deleter for the unique_ptr, and it sets it to point at whatever data is sent as an argument? Also, since i'm using smart pointers, when the list object goes out of bounds, will the underlying link list de allocate itself?